# What library can I use to read Jsonlite with .NET?

Tags: c#, json

I had a Json file without quotes and commas, I did some research and found out that that's Jsonlite files from [this article](https://deerchao.cn/projects/jsonlite/).

And a little more research leads me to the conclusion that that's something used in R.

I then go download R.Net in Nuget, but it seems not to give me anything related to Jsonlite.

And I can't find anything if I search "jsonlite" in Nuget, neither could I find anything teaching me how to read Jsonlite files in C# from Google.

Is there any library I can use to read/parse Jsonlite files in C#?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Gladly! Funnily I cannot remove that comment by "community". It says it will automatically be removed "when the post is corrected" (which it was already)…

Answer (score 0):

VS Code has an extension ([Fix JSON](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oliversturm.fix-json)) that 'repairs' bad json syntax using a JS library named 'jsonic'.

I searched for modules based on *jsoinc*, and found one that might match:

> GitHub: https://github.com/mimirproj/Mimir.Jsonic
>
> NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mimir.Jsonic

Hope this helps.